# Event handling for Combobox in listbox(with databinding)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, prism

I am at my wit's end on this... so I have a classic products-categories scenario. Product belongs to a category. my list box source is products and each product will again have a combobox for categories. My issue is, SelectionChanged doesn't seem to fire. All data shows up fine as it should. Combo boxes load fine etc. Not sure how to debug this..
.......

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ProductDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="vertical">
//resources here...
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProductName}" ></TextBlock>
                <ComboBox Background="Transparent" SelectedValuePath="CategoryId" DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                        <CompositeCollection>
                            <models:Category CategoryName="Select" CategoryId="{x:Static sys:Guid.Empty}" Order="0"/>
                            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=categories}}" />
                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>  
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
```

and my listbox elsewhere is:

```
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ProductDataTemplate}" Height="Auto" Margin="50,256,50,64" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
```

and my viewmodel is standard stuff:

```
public ICommand SetSelectionChangedCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(param => this.SetSelectionChangedExecute(param), null); } }
private void SetSelectionChangedExecute(object param)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Selected");
}
```

What's wrong with what I have.. why doesn't control come to the handler when I select a random category for a random product? My RelayCommand below:

```
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
}
```

**Edit:**
I have a feeling my issue is the command binding path is not correct. How would it know to go look in the ViewModel? My ViewModel is set as the DataContext for an ancestor Grid that is way way up in the hierarchy. Is that enough? Or do I have to properly qualify the Path in the Command Binding?:

```
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
```

What do I have to do to make sure Command is searched for in my ViewModel?

Comment: I tried the same in a sample application and it seem to working fine. Could you post `ICommand.CanExecute` code from your `RelayCommand`?

Comment: @sthotakura question updated with RelayCommand. Elsewhere, the Commands all work fine. But not here..

Comment: @sthotakura did you try with a compositecollection too? May be that is the reason? I will see how it behaves if it is a direct binding instead of compisite. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, I didn't try `CompositeCollection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is, we need to specify the Path properly in Command Binding:

```
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid, AncestorLevel=1}}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found an inconsistency while reviewing the code implementation you showed to us:

In the ***SelectionChanged Event Trigger*** at **Product DataTemplate** implementation, you are binding the command to **`SelectionChangedCommand`**.

However, I see that in the **ViewModel**, the *SelectionChanged Command* is declared as **`SetSelectionChangedCommand`**. You added a ***'Set'*** prefix on the ViewModel's command definition.

Take into account that the *Binding* would not throw any exception if the path reference is not found. Instead, it would work as triggering an inexistent command which would do nothing, and the application would continue without any warnings.

I hope this helps.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. I fixed that. Still no luck. Something else I am missing..